# two adobe air native extensions using google-play-services jar file

Tags: java, android, jar, air, air-native-extension

I have two .ane extensions and they both require the google-play-services jar file to work successfully. when I use them separately in my mobile Air project, they work just fine. but when I need them both in one project, they conflict with each other:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
com/google/android/gms/appstate/OnStateListLoadedListener;
```

I wonder if there is a way so I don't put the google-play-services jar file in one of them and then create the .ane and yet when using it in the project that is using the other extension (which of course includes the google jar) then the former extension would work fine?

let me put it this way, how can my extension use the google-play-services jar file without combining the google jar file into my extension jar file and instead it will use what it needs from other extension that already has the google jar combined in the extension...?

am I clear in explaining what my problem is?! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AIR 4.0 has a solution for this.

If you look in [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/index.html)

Developing Native Extensions for Adobe AIR
 / Developing Native Extensions
Packaging a native extension / [Including resources in your native extension package](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7ff8.html)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7ff8.html

You will see an example in the section: "Accessing native resources with R.* mechanism"

To quote:

> Following is an example of the dependencies in platform.xml:

```
<packagedDependencies> 
    <packagedDependency>android-support-v4.jar</packagedDependency> 
    <packagedDependency>google-play-services.jar</packagedDependency> 
</packagedDependencies> 
<packagedResources> 
  <packagedResource> 
        <packageName>com.myane.sampleasextension</packageName> 
        <folderName>ane-res</folderName> 
    </packagedResource> 
    <packagedResource> 
        <packageName>com.google.android.gms</packageName> 
        <folderName>google-play-services-res</folderName> 
    </packagedResource> 
</packagedResources>
```